# layout scrollable doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml

i don't know why but my layout is not scrollable...
Now i show you my code!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >
        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/signor_pomidor"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_logut_bg" />

        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_logut_bg"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will solve your problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:hint="mail"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:hint="password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <!-- Login Button -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:text="btn_login"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:text="btn_login"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:text="btn_login"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:text="btn_login"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="btn_link_to_register"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```